# Debug Assertion Failed! String manipulation using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

**EDIT: Pastebin links to the entirety of the code at the bottom**

for my CS215 course, I was given a class called String215 which is a basic string class to help in the understanding of dynamic memory allocation and pointer arithmetic with char arrays.

The class was given to me in a very basic skeleton form with prototypes but no implementations, along with a test function to test my implementations. I CAN NOT use any C String functions in this assignment.

The part of the program which is troubling is the append function, which just appends a parameter string215 object to the end of the current string215 object.

```
// Add a suffix to the end of this string.  Allocates and frees memory.
void string215::append(const string215 &suffix)
{
    char *output = new char[str_len(data)+suffix.length()+1];
    for(int x = 0; x < str_len(data); x++) {
            *output = *data;
        output++;
        data++;
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < suffix.length(); x++) {
        *output = suffix.getchar(x);
        output++;
    }
    *output = '\0';
    output -= (str_len(data)+suffix.length()+1);
    delete[] data;
    data = output;
}
```

This portion of the code is tested in the 13th test of the test function as shown here:

```
string215 str("testing");

...

// Test 13: test that append works in a simple case.
curr_test++;
string215 suffix("123");
str.append(suffix);
if (strcmp(str.c_str(), "testing123") != 0) {
    cerr << "Test " << curr_test << " failed." << endl;
    failed++;
}
```

Here is the description of the append class:

> Add the suffix to the end of this string. Allocates a new, larger, array; copies the old contents, followed by the suffix, to the new array; then frees the old array and updates the pointer to the new one.

My program aborts at the very end of the append function execution with the error message:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: [Source path]\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

...

Abort || Retry || Ignore
```

I'm fairly certain it has something to do with my very poor memory management. I know it's not a lot to go on, but I've been struggling with this for hours on end and can't seem to figure it out.

Here's a pastebin of the .cpp and .h file for this program

string215.cpp: http://pastebin.com/Xh2SvDKJ

string215.h: http://pastebin.com/JfAJDEVN

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
RAW-BERRY

Answer (score 0):

You increment `output` exactly `str_len(data) + suffix.length()` times. Note that you don't increment `output` after `*output = '\0';`.

So to go back to the start, you should use:

```
output -= (str_len(data) + suffix.length());
```

By the way, some of the code is not very efficient. For example, `getchar` uses a loop instead of simply returning `data[index]`. You use `getchar` in `append`, which means that the performance isn't great.

**EDIT:** As zch says, you use `delete[] data` after modifying `data`, but note that even before that you use `str_len(data)` after modifying `data` (when deciding how many bytes to go skip back), so the calculation is wrong (and my suggestion above is also wrong, because `str_len(data)` is now zero).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I figured out my original problem, now it's on to the next one! A Heap Corruption T_T

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `data` pointer before `delete[]`. You need to `delete[]` exactly the same value you got from `new[]`.

Also, you are incrementing `output` pointer `str_len(data)+suffix.length()` times, and you take it back by `str_len(data) + suffix.length() + 1`.

I would use separate variables for iteration to solve these problems.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense! Checking the local variables while I step through the execution of the append function confirms that output contains the correct value, so that's good! However, now I'm getting a HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED error, which from what I can tell typically means I didn't allocate memory properly? Do I need to reallocate memory for data? Should I just make a new post?

Answer (score 0):

So I think your problem is with the line

```
for(int x = 0; x < str_len(data); x++) {
```

Notice that the size of 'data' is changing at each iteration of the loop. As you increment 'x', you are decreasing the length of 'data'. Suppose 'data' is a string holding "hello": in the first iteration of the loop x=0 and str_len(data)=5; in the second iteration x=1 and str_len(data)=4. Thus the for loop executes half as many times as you need it to and 'data' does not end up pointing to the end of the data string